# sort associative array by key value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I try to sort my array by "delais_livraison" by DESC in php but i dont know how i can do that

In the first level I expected to have in first `Etoile => 25` and then `Feuillage => 10`

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Feuillage] => Array
                        (
                            [delais_livraison] => 10
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Étoiles] => Array
                        (
                            [delais_livraison] => 25
                        )
                )
        )
    [B] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Grenouillère] => Array
                        (
                            [delais_livraison] => 7
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Chaussons] => Array
                        (
                            [delais_livraison] => 0
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Edit :
this how my array has been build
[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wd1CBKSd)

Comment: Provide desired output. Try to use var_export or json_encode.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and the result you are getting.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to look at how you create this array now you know what you want to do with it. It does not seem particularly well designed for this purpose and probably not for any other purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$data = array(
    'A' => array(
        array('Feuillage'    => array('delais_livraison' => 10)),
        array('Étoiles'      => array('delais_livraison' => 25)),
    ),
    'B' => array(
        array('Grenouillère' => array('delais_livraison' => 7)),
        array('Chaussons'    => array('delais_livraison' => 0)),
    ),
);

foreach ($data as &$group) {
    usort($group, function($itemA, $itemB){
        $a = current($itemA)['delais_livraison'];
        $b = current($itemB)['delais_livraison'];
        if ($a == $b) return 0;
        return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
    });
}
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  'A' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'Étoiles' => 
            array (size=1)
              'delais_livraison' => int 25
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'Feuillage' => 
            array (size=1)
              'delais_livraison' => int 10
  'B' => &
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'Grenouillère' => 
            array (size=1)
              'delais_livraison' => int 7
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'Chaussons' => 
            array (size=1)
              'delais_livraison' => int 0
```

Solution uses [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) that has been introduced in PHP `5.3.0`. For older versions just create a function and specify it in `usort` function:

```
function my_sort_function($itemA, $itemB){
    // ...
}
usort($group, 'my_sort_function');
```

Comment: current doesn't work for me i had this error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Comment: Beat me by seconds, works for me, perfectly. @LudwigRodrigues You must have messed up when you copied it to your code and changed field names. you should only need to chnage the `$data` in the first foreach loop to the name of your variable holding the array.

Answer (score 0):

Since your array has two levels, how do you want to manage a **global** sort ?
Do you want to do a sort for each sub array ( A, B, ...) ?

In this case the approach will be to use function [uksort](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_uksort.asp) for each sub array (A and B) and define your own compare function to compare delais_livraison values.

Answer (score -1):

You would appear to be looking for [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php), or, if you have to supply your own comparison function, [`uksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php).

Comment: Hwo is a key sort going to help him